# Unable to solve error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

please check what's the error. Thanks in advance.

```kotlin
@Dao
interface FavDishDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertFavDishDetails(favDish: FavDish)

   
    @Query("SELECT * FROM FAV_DISHES_TABLE ORDER BY ID")
    fun getAllDishesList(): Flow<List<FavDish>>

    @Update
    suspend fun updateFavDishDetails(favDish: FavDish)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM FAV_DISHES_TABLE WHERE favorite_dish = 1")
    fun getFavoriteDishesList(): Flow<List<FavDish>>
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to show a little bit more effort in your question. The only thing you posted is the code, so please at least format it next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

If You have annotated your entity and instantiated database properly then this is actually the same problem I faced just go to your build.gradle(app) file and there you could see warnings in you dependencies(highlighted in yellow).
Press ctrl+alt+shift+s(basically the open option) then go to dependencies(as shown in the image below) and then one by one on all your dependencies check whether there is an update variable option available in the details part if yes click on that.
Once you are done with all of them click apply after that click ok and that would sync your gradle.

Now try to run your app.

PS:-As others have suggested try to be a little more descriptive with your question the next time.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. my room version was not latest

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve a kind of similar issue downgrading the Kotlin version to "1.4.32"

Comment: I had the same problem when updating kotlin to 1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

You have to annotate your data class `FavDish` with `@Entity(tableName="FAV_DISHES_TABLE")` for creating a table for this data class in your Room database.